# PDF Duplex not working - Between Windows 10 and XP

Tags: windows-xp, pdf, printing

I have a very odd issue. Only certain types of PDF file (PDF/A-1B) will not print duplex in Windows 10, while they print fine in Windows XP.

The setup is as so:

**Windows XP - SP3**

- Applications: Acrobat Reader DC, Foxit
- Print Server (Windows
  NT)(32bit)
- Printer - Xerox DocuPrint C2255 (PS Driver)
- Driver -
  PSCRIPT5 v0.3.6000.16386 Pv 6.0.6000.16386

**Windows 10**

- Applications: Acrobat Reader DC, Foxit
- Print Server (Windows Server 2008)(64bit)
- Printer - Xerox DocuPrint C2255 (PS Driver)
- Driver - PSCRIPT5 v0.3.7601.17514 Pv 6.1.7601.17514

All the settings have been matched between the two print servers.

The outcome is on Windows XP with duplex selected, the PDF file will print out as expected, duplexed. 
On Windows 10 with duplex selected, 2 single sided prints will come out.

Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Caz

Comment: Can you print _anything else_ duplex on that host? If not, then the problem is more general, i.e. printer drivers.

Comment: Yes so most other PDF files print duplex fine along with doc and ppt files

Comment: One difference I am unsure about is that on the Windows NT box there are multiple print processors. This printer uses HPPRN05 on the NT box and the standard windows processor on the 2008 machine. Not 100% sure what ramifications occur from changing these?